# JsTree Get selected node siblings and sub-siblings ids

Tags: jstree

I am using jstree to draw departments as a tree, this issue is that if I clicked on the a Node(root) I will only get first siblings IDs; however I want to get sub-siblings id's that are related to the same root as well.

Here is my code:

```
     var currentNode = $("#jstree").jstree("get_selected");
     var childrens = $("#jstree").jstree("get_children_dom", currentNode);
    for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++) {
      alert(childrens[i].id);
    }
```

Comment: Use the `get_json` function and traverse through the nodes for siblings

Comment: can you please show me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jsTree `get_node` function to get the node's JSON representation which includes an array of all the nodes siblings.

```
$('#jstree').bind('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var tree = $('#jstree').jstree(true);
    var siblings = tree.get_node(data.selected).children_d;
    console.log(siblings);
});
```